# Angular - Hide Div when form text input is not blank

Tags: angularjs

Basically i would like for one dive to be hidden when someone adds text to a box.

I have a form where someone can either upload an image or add a link to an image. When the user adds an image link i would like to hide the upload button

Right now i have it that when they select an image to upload the text box will be hidden but i cant get the vice versa working.

**Id like to hide the div "manual-upload" when a user adds text to the data-ng-model="dealsCTRL.urlimage"**

```
<div class="manual-upload">

                              <div class="text-center form-group controls" ng-hide="uploaderProduct.queue.length">
                            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                Select Image <input type="file" nv-file-select uploader="uploaderProduct">

                            </span>
                              </div>

                              <div class="sub-label"> Upload an image of product.</div></br>

                              <div class="text-center form-group" ng-show="uploaderProduct.queue.length">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="uploadProductPicture();">Upload</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancelProductUpload();">Delete</button>
                              </div>



                              <div ng-show="success" class="text-center text-success">
                                <strong>Upload Successful</strong>
                              </div>
                              <div ng-show="error" class="text-center text-danger">
                                <strong ng-bind="error"></strong>
                              </div>

                              </div>

                              <div class="add-image-link">

                              <label class="control-label" for="urlimage" ng-hide="uploaderProduct.queue.length">IMAGE URL</label>

                              <div class="controls" ng-hide="uploaderProduct.queue.length">
                                <input type="url" data-ng-model="dealsCTRL.urlimage" id="urlimage" class="form-control"
                                       placeholder="Image URL" ng-change="blankPhoto()" required>

                                <div class="sub-label">Manually enter an image URL.</div>

                              </div>

                              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
<div class="manual-upload" ng-show="dealsCTRL.urlimage.length === 0">
```

Comment: Seems to be always hidden. seems to work better if i change it to <div class="manual-upload" ng-show="dealsCTRL.urlimage.length === undefined"> but it doesnt hide if i type a single letter in the box.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the element when you start typing so

```
div class="manual-upload" ng-hide="dealsCTRL.urlimage.length > 0"
```